# Does elmah support teradata database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, teradata, elmah

I am using elmah for exception handling in my asp.net mvc application also i am using teradata as my database. Can i log the exceptions in teradata database using elmah?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does elmah documentation say about this?

Comment: I don't find any reference about teradata in elmah documentation.

Comment: That's a strong indication it is not supported out of the box. Are there any information there on creating a data sink for a custom data storage?

Comment: No I don't find any information about data sink for custom storage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's an ErrorLog implementation for teradata. But there's an implementation for Entity Framework (https://github.com/abatishchev/Elmah.Contrib.EntityFramework) and as I read it, teradata supports Entity Framework through their ADO.NET provider (http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/EntityProviderFeatures.html). If there's a version match, I do not know. Would be worth a shot though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to do it via entity framework.